# How to enable Camera Preview on a Click or Tap in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-camera2

I am a newbie in Jetpack Compose want to achieve the below. User can click/tap the preview box and it enable or disable camera preview accordingly.

[image]

Currently I am using the below code to display the preview.

```
AndroidView(
                factory = { context ->
                    val previewView = PreviewView(context)
                    val preview = Preview.Builder().build()
                    val selector = CameraSelector.Builder()
                        .requireLensFacing(CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK)
                        .build()
                    preview.setSurfaceProvider(previewView.surfaceProvider)
                    val imageAnalysis = ImageAnalysis.Builder()
                        .setTargetResolution(
                            Size(
                                previewView.width,
                                previewView.height
                            )
                        )
                        .setBackpressureStrategy(ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST)
                        .build()
                    imageAnalysis.setAnalyzer(
                        ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(context),
                       
                    )
                    try {
                        cameraProviderFuture.get().bindToLifecycle(
                            lifecycleOwner,
                            selector,
                            preview,
                            imageAnalysis
                        )
                    } catch (e: Exception) {
                        e.printStackTrace()
                    }
                    previewView
                },
                modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
            )
```

Thanks in advance. Please help.